# MPI too many communicators?

Tags: fortran, mpi, communicator

The idea of the code is to open a file in parallel and then each
core reads different part of that big file. `ir_start` and `ir_stop` are therefore different for each core.

I have the following code (part of a much bigger code):

```
DO iq = 1, nqf
  IF (MOD(iq,100) == 0) THEN
      WRITE(stdout, '(a,i10,a,i10)' ) '     Progression iq (fine) = ',iq,'/',nqf
  ENDIF
  CALL MPI_FILE_OPEN (world_comm,filint,MPI_MODE_RDONLY,MPI_INFO_NULL,iunepmatwp2,ierr)
  IF( ierr /= 0 ) CALL errore( 'xxxx', 'error in MPI_FILE_OPEN',1 )

  DO ir = ir_start, ir_stop
    CALL MPI_FILE_SEEK(iunepmatwp2,lrepmatw,MPI_SEEK_SET,ierr)
    CALL MPI_FILE_READ(iunepmatwp2, aux, lrepmatw2, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,ierr)
     loops:
        eptmp ( ibnd, jbnd, ip, imode ) = aux (i)
     endloops
     CALL mp_sum(eptmp, world_comm)
  ENDDO
  something is then done with eptmp
ENDDO
```

The problem that the code systematically crash at:

```
 ...
 Progression iq (fine) =      32000/     50000
 Progression iq (fine) =      32100/     50000
 Progression iq (fine) =      32200/     50000
 Progression iq (fine) =      32300/     50000
 Progression iq (fine) =      32400/     50000
 Progression iq (fine) =      32500/     50000
 Progression iq (fine) =      32600/     50000
 error in MPI_FILE_OPEN
```

It look to me (I might be totally wrong) that there might be too 
many communicators open.

The problem is that I cannot do something like `CALL MPI_Comm_free(world_comm)` in the `q`-loop because it kills the code.

Is there a way for each core to use the same `world_comm` without creating new one?

Comment: You don't show any communicator creation in your code at all? Why do you believe there may be too many of them? Why can't you just do `world_comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD` or similar?

Comment: You should be able to get an error code and you should print it. Just `error in MPI_FILE_OPEN` doesn't tell much. Also you could just use `MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL`.

Comment: Do you mean file handles rather than communicators?  Why do you repeatedly open the file inside that outer loop?  (And what are those `loops:` and `endloops`?)

Comment: I don't see you calling `MPI_FILE_CLOSE`. If not really present in your code, then you are most likely hitting the OS limit on simultaneously opened file descriptors.

Comment: @ Hristo Iliev: Silly me ! Thanks a lot ! How do I mark you comment as the accepted answer ?